# Разбить 2D массив на блоки

Tags: python, массивы, изображения, numpy

Есть 2D массив numpy(512x512).
Нужно разбить его на 'блоки' заданной формы и собрать обратно.
**Дано:**

```
[[3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17],
[5,7,11,13,15,17,19,21],
[7,11,13,15,17,19,21,23],
[9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23],
[11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25],
[13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27],
[15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29],
[17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31]]
```

**Получить:**

```
 array1      array2
[[3,5,7,9,   |11,13,15,17],
[5,7,11,13,  |15,17,19,21],
[7,11,13,15, |17,19,21,23],
[9,11,13,15, |17,19,21,23],
--------------------------
[11,13,15,17,|19,21,23,25],
[13,15,17,19,|21,23,25,27],
[15,17,19,21,|23,25,27,29],
[17,19,21,23,|25,27,29,31]]
array3        array4
```

Основная сложность - как сеё сделать для большого массива 512x512 и разбить на блоки 8x8, поработать со значениями и собрать обратно.

Comment: Что значит поработать со значениями? Что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: @MaxU Поработать со значениями к вопросу не относится, я не могу разбить один большой 2d массив на несколько малых 2d массивов по принципу, описанному мною выше. Я нашел один способ в пакете skimage (from skimage.util import view_as_blocks), но не могу понять как потом в правильном порядке (исходном) восстановить массив.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь реализовать свёртку (convolution) вручную ?

Comment: Не надо разбивать на блоки, просто обрабатывайте блоки и присваивайте блок оригинальной матрице или её копии